PIVOT TABLE : "There is already data in worksheet, do you want to replace it?" is there any VBA code to find the cells to be replaced?
PIVOT TABLE : "There is already data in worksheet, do you want to replace it?" is there any VBA code to find the cells to be replaced?
working in Excel, I´m updating all the pivot tables in a workbook, and I get the "There is already data in worksheet, do you want to replace it?" message, indicating the worksheet, but not the address
is there any VBA code to find the cells to be replaced?
thanks!
I've searched but only found VBA to find overlaping pivot tables

Do you update pivot tables manually or programmatically? If manually, your eyes is the tool to look below the table and to right to identify occupied cells. Programmatically you need to do same: check if enough space is available for the growing table.

both!
the problem is that I have more than 75 PT

And you have more than a PT per sheet? Or what else besides?

yes, at least 20 per sheet

It looks like a task to hire the freelancer.

the only thing I can think of is to loop through each PT and every cell on each sheet and see if the cell is in a PT.

any advise or vb code is welcomed!

You already have the worksheet per your question, so loop through the pivot tables on that sheet.
You have 3 ranges to test around each pivot table.  The area directly to the right, the area directly below, and the area directly down and to the right.  How many rows and columns to check is probably a judgment call.
This may get you started:
Sub LoopPvtTbls_ActiveSheet()
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim pvtAddress As String
Dim pvtRows As Integer
Dim pvtCols As Integer
Dim chkRows, chkCols As Integer     'number of rows and columns below and to the right of table to check
Dim a, b, c As Range

chkRows = 10        'Select a reasonable number to check
chkCols = 10        'Select a reasonable number to check

'Loop through each PivotTable in ActiveSheet
For Each pvt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
    
    'Get the address and row count
    pvtAddress = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).TableRange2.Address
    pvtRows = pvt.TableRange2.Rows.Count
    
    'Check 3 ranges.  Area to directrly to the right of table (a), area directly below table (b), and an area down and right of table (c)
    Set a = Cells(pvt.TableRange2.Row, pvt.TableRange2.Columns.Count).Offset(, 1).Resize(pvtRows, chkCols)
    Set b = Cells(pvt.TableRange2.Row, pvt.TableRange2.Column).Offset(pvtRows).Resize(chkRows, pvt.TableRange2.Columns.Count)
    Set c = Cells(pvt.TableRange2.Row, pvt.TableRange2.Columns.Count).Offset(pvtRows, 1).Resize(chkRows, chkCols)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(a) Then MsgBox ("Range " & a.Address & "is not empty to right of pivot table " & pvt.Name)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(b) Then MsgBox ("Range " & a.Address & "is not empty below pivot table " & pvt.Name)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(c) Then MsgBox ("Range " & a.Address & "is not empty below and to the right of pivot tagble " & pvt.Name)
Next pvt
End Sub

You can find the first non-empty cell in the range with:
a.Find(what:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas).Address

